# .NET Framework prerequisite requirements if application build with .NET 3.5 SP1?

Tags: .net, deployment, .net-3.5

What versions need to be present on a user machine if I want to install an application (desktop [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)) made mostly out of [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 3.5 SP1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WPF` requires at least .NET 3.0 to be installed on the client machine. If you referenced `System.Core` and used LINQ you might need .NET 3.5.

Comment: Should v1.1,v1.1sp1,v2.0,v2.0sp1, + v3.0 + v3.0sp1 be there ?

Comment: If you install 3.5 SP1, it will already include 2.0 and 3.0, so you don't need to install them apart.

Comment: But what about v1.1,v1.1sp1 do they need to be installed to install 3.5SP1 ?

Comment: All you need to install is .NET 3.5 SP1, nothing more.